# Reading Outlook Calendars [The request is not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration.]

Tags: python, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Today I'm trying to do read calendar from outlook. I created a new app through Microsoft Azure then setted a secret key and added a api permissions. When I was trying to authenticate via simple script I caught an error

```
The request is not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration. 
In order to use /common/ endpoint%2c the application must not be configured with 'Consumer' as the user audience. 
The userAudience should be configured with 'All' to use /common/ endpoint
```

This is my script

```
from O365 import Account, MSGraphProtocol

CLIENT_ID = 'MY CLIENT ID'
SECRET_ID = 'MY SECRET ID'

credentials = (CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID)
protocol = MSGraphProtocol()
scopes = ['Calendars.Read.Shared']
account = Account(credentials, protocol=protocol)

if account.authenticate(scopes=scopes):
    print('Authenticated!')
```

Could you tell me a reason of this error and how should i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you trying to use the client_credentials flow but your firstly using a Delegate permission which isn't correct. So in your Application registration you need to make sure you have assigned the Application permission for Calendars eg [image]

to use the Client_credentials flow you need to first find your tenantId (if you don't already know it) you can do this in python eg using requests (you need to replace yourdomain.com with the domain your using

```
requests.get('https://login.windows.net/yourdomain.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration').json()["token_endpoint"]
```

Then take the guid part of the response eg

```
'https://login.windows.net/1c3a18bf-da31-4f6c-xxxx-2c06c9cf5ae4/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Then your code should look like where

```html
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='1c3a18bf-da31-4f6c-xxxx-2c06c9cf5ae4')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
```

Comment: Thank you. As I use It as app now I should provide resourses. Could you tell me please how to provide access to someone's account for my app. I want to get calendar

Comment: If you using a daemon base app where the user isn't logging on then the above is the correct method. If the app is being run by the user then you need some form of interactive login eg https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core

Comment: I got it. But when I try to get my calendar doing this

`schedule = account.schedule(resource='my_account@domain')
calendar = schedule.get_default_calendar()
events = calendar.get_events(include_recurring=False)`

I get an error: Error Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood. It seems to me I should provide access. But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Have the permissions in the screenshot been granted in the application registration and have then been consented to in the tenant ? It sounds similar to https://github.com/O365/python-o365/issues/427 which was caused by the consent issue

Comment: Yea I've chosen an application permissions. So I need someone's approval?

Comment: Also a question. I need a subscription on azure ad to do it? All I want to make a service, which can read and write outlook calendars of some group. I need to make it for my university project

Comment: So for your uni project are you trying to read calendars of a group of other students with mailboxes (i guess in your uni tenant)? if so its probably going to be difficult to get the app permission consent in that context. You can get an Office365 developer subscription https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program create some mailboxes (or use the auto generated ones) and build your application to work against those mailboxes. You then have full control over the underlying Azure Ad associated with you subscription and you will be able to approve the permissions.

Comment: The other option would be to use Mail.Read.Shared delegate permission (which doesn't require admin consent) and for each student to grant your account access to read their Calendar. Your app would then need to login as you and should then be able to access the other student accounts.